# Is passing error to express middleware next function supported?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

In the article on Express webisite [Writing Middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html)

The next function does not take any parameters. Most middlewares I've seen do not pass any parameters into next function, but I came across serve-static middleware and in their implementation of next function they sometimes pass an error to next()

Is it correct to pass error to next() function when writing own middleware? Is this something that Express framework expects/supports by default?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can send error through next() both in your routes and in middlewares.

you can also defines error handler like this :

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    // handle the error
});
```

Note that instead of the usual three parameters error handlers take a fourth one containing the error.

For more details you should have a look here : https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this the standard way to raise an error while still allowing other middleware in the chain to execute.

You can see this in the [express source code for route.js](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/route.js#L114-L134):

```
function next(err) {

    // ....

    if (err) {
      layer.handle_error(err, req, res, next);
    } 

    // ....
}
```